# Is there any option to use Connect.data.com with excel?

Tags: data.com

Is there an application to use data.com appexchange with excel if I want to clean up the data?There are many applications which directly cleans from salesforce but is there any option to clean from excel or would I have to import the data into salesforce and would then use data.com